# How to disable string interpolation in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, string-interpolation

I have a text like `"$ $abc $$abc ${a} ${}"`. I would like to completely disable string interpolation for the string and not to escape each and individual `$` from the string. What should I do? In Scala you declare a string where interpolation is enabled with `s"$ $abc $$abc ${a} ${}"` while the normal string is not interpolated.

Answer (score 9):

String interpolation is available for both regular and raw strings (`"""`). So you need to escape them, which is easier in a regular `String` obviously (see [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates)).

```
"$ \$abc \$\$abc \${a} \${}"
```

I'm sorry but there's no other way I'm afraid.

Comment: It would actually be nice to have something like C# verbatim string `@"$a$b$c" == "\$a\$b\$c"`, no?

Comment: Too bad the single quote syntax has been kept only for chars. IMO Kotlin semantic tree can consider that '$' and 'x' are single chars while '$$' and 'xx' are non interpolated strings, since you can always use "\$" and "x" for one char length strings. Maybe in a future version? Since the evolution is fully backward compatible (apart from parsing test cases expecting a parse error), it's perfectly doable.